# Get a different class based on a config value in JAVA

Tags: java

I am working on a program that supports 3 different platforms. These platforms have identical logic, but the program would have to work with a different database for each one.

I have three different `Database.java` files for each platform. For example

```
com.myproject.dao.bmw.Database.java
com.myproject.dao.ford.Database.java
com.myproject.dao.chevy.Database.java
```

The Database classes all have the same method signatures. But their database connection or queries may be different.

I set the platform name, which in this case is the car make using a `config.properties` file. I call the methods inside the Database class depending on which platform is set in the `config.properties` file throughout the program many times.

I want to have to get the Database object based in what is set on the `config.properties` file when the program starts, while having the same object name for the database. That way each time I call the method names I would not have to use if statements or switches each time I want to use a method in the Database class.

What is the best way to achieve my goal?.

Comment: You should let the 3 classes implement a single `interface`, and let the `interface` define some common methods, which the 3 concrete classes have to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the Factory pattern.

1. Create an interface `CarDB` (or `ICarDb` if you like the naming convention like that so you know it is an interface) that contains all the common methods
2. Create 3 classes that implement `CarDB` - `Ford`, `Bmw` and `Chevy`
3. Create a `CarDbFactory` that has a method like `CarDB getDb(Params params)` that given your parameters will return a `CarDB` - the actual one (Ford, Bmw...) depends on the paremeters.

Comment: Actually, factory is more for creating the cars etc via the config file. Using `interface` is back to the basic OOP concept - *abstraction*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you did not mention any reasons why you are not considering any of the [existing ORM frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) which is meant specifically for this job. In a nutshell, the **ORM allows you to switch across the different databases** easily. But if you have a strong reason for not to use the [ORM framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Java), then you can consider the below approach.

Basically, need to define and use the `DataBaseConfigFactory` and set the appropriate `DBConfiguration` during the start up of your application as shown below:

**DataBaseConfigFactory interface:**

```
public interface DataBaseConfigFactory {
    Connection getConnection();
    void executeQuery();
}
```

**MyProjectDataBaseConfigFactory class:**

```
public class MyProjectDataBaseConfigFactory implements DataBaseConfigFactory {

    private static final DBConfiguration dbConfiguration;

    static {
        // Get the active db name from props file
        // Set dbConfiguration to BmwDBConfiguration or FordDBConfiguration, etc...
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
         return dbConfiguration.getConnection();
    }

    public void executeQuery() {
        return dbConfiguration.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

Now define a `DBConfiguration` interface and all specific implementations for the operations that your bmw, ford, etc.. support

**DBConfiguration class:**

```
public interface DBConfiguration {
    //Add all methods that can be supported by DBConfiguration
}


public class BmwDBConfiguration implements DBConfiguration {
    // BMW specific implementations for DBConfiguration
}


public class FordDBConfiguration implements DBConfiguration{
    // Ford specific implementations for DBConfiguration
}
```

In short, you will be using `DataBaseConfigFactory` interface through out your application to connect with databases and if a new database is added then you need to set the `DBConfiguration` appropriately.